# in Drupal 9, when open the people BTN from admin account it says "The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later."

Tags: drupal, content-management-system, cpanel

STR:

- Open My Drupal live website
- Log in with my drupal admin account
- from the admin toolbar click on "people" to add users or manage thier roles

Actual result:
a white page with a paragraph says: "The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later."

[Screen shot for the result page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgFKG.png)

I tried to manage my users roles and add some new users, i expected to open the page that had all users and thier roles